# Using god with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, god

I am using RVM and wish to use god.  I have it working on my local machine which has a very similar set up to my remote server (RVM, ruby 1.9.1, rails 3.0.3.)

On my local machine I did:

```
rvm wrapper uploader bootup god
```

This created a file in ~/.rvm/bin called bootup.god with the contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -s "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180-grabbio" ]] ; then
  source "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180-grabbio"
  exec god "$@"
else
  echo "ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180-grabbio'" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

I ran the same command on my remote server, but when I try to execute god with:

```
sudo /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/bootup_god -c uploader.god -D --log /var/log/god.log
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/bootup_god: line 5: exec: god: not found
```

How can I get god running on my remote machine?

Cheers,
Gazler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing sudo apt-get install god, which should mean the gemset is still determined by the ruby version and the god executable is still available.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `rvmsudo` instead of `sudo`.